# Visual Studio display issues under Windows 10

Tags: windows, display, windows-10, visual-studio

After upgrade to Windows 10, I encounter Visual Studio (e.g. VS2013 Ultimate) display issues.

Take its start page as an example, it turns out

[image]

, where it should be if no problem at all

[image]

Other notes:

1. The problem also happens for the latest VS2015.
2. Besides the start page, it has similar display problem in its code editor, see the following screenshot:

[image]

Could someone kindly suggest how to solve this?

Comment: Check Tools-Options-General-Visual Experience, try turning off the visual experience and graphics acceleration checkboxes. Also check for your graphics driver update

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Thanks a lot! It worked. I will try to update my graphics driver and re-turn on these options to have a look.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo You should turn your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Tools-Options-General-Visual Experience, uncheck the Visual Experience and Graphics Acceleration. If possible, update the graphics driver and try re-enabling the options afterwards.

Comment: Thanks turning off acceleration helped solve the issue. I should point out that this only happened for me after upgrading to the latest NVidia drivers which Windows 10 pushed as an update.